# Histogram of a RGB image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I wrote some C++ code using the OpenCV library. The program reads the image and plot histograms of Red, Green, and Blue components. I am very new to OpenCV so I need comments and advice. What do you think about my code? Is there any better way to do that? Are there unnecessary parts in my code? Is there any part I should change?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(){
    Mat image = imread("C:/image.jpg");
    int HistR[257] = {0};
    int HistG[257] = {0};
    int HistB[257] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
        {
            Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i));
            int Red = intensity.val[0];
            int Green = intensity.val[1];
            int Blue = intensity.val[2];
            HistR[Red] = HistR[Red]+1;
            HistB[Blue] = HistB[Blue]+1;
            HistG[Green] = HistG[Green]+1;
        }
    Mat HistPlotR (500, 256, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    Mat HistPlotG (500, 256, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    Mat HistPlotB (500, 256, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i=i+2)
    {
        line(HistPlotR, Point(i, 500), Point(i, 500-HistR[i]), Scalar(0, 0, 255),1,8,0);
        line(HistPlotG, Point(i, 500), Point(i, 500-HistG[i]), Scalar(0, 255, 0),1,8,0);
        line(HistPlotB, Point(i, 500), Point(i, 500-HistB[i]), Scalar(255, 0, 0),1,8,0);
    }
    namedWindow("Red Histogram");
    namedWindow("Green Histogram");
    namedWindow("Blue Histogram");
    imshow("Red Histogram", HistPlotR);
    imshow("Green Histogram", HistPlotG);
    imshow("Blue Histogram", HistPlotB);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you avoid the [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) function on purpose ?

Comment: @Loufylouf I know that function. I just tried to figure out how it woks and made some code exercise. If I used just calcHist function, it wasn't in the Code Review field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, this is pretty straightforward, easy-to-read code. Nicely done.

As @Loufylouf mentioned in the comments, there is a function in OpenCV that calculates a histogram already - the [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) function. You'd be better off using that. But it doesn't hurt to try to do it yourself just to see how it's done.

You're calculating the histogram of an image with 8-bit per channel RGB pixels. You only need 256 bins, not 257. You're allocating an extra int for each histogram. That's not a huge problem, but you don't need it. (Unlike C strings, arrays do not need a terminating value or anything like that.)

Also, there's a lot of magic numbers in the code. Instead of:

```
int HistR[256] = { 0 };
```

You could tell a potential future reader of your code what the 256 (or 257) is. Something like:

```
const int MAX_BINS = 256;
...
int HistR[MAX_BINS] = { 0 };
```

Or, since the reason you have 256 bins is because the values you're analyzing are unsigned 8-bit characters, you could use the predefined `UINT8_MAX` constant. (It's in stdint.h.) Just remember to add `1` to it.

If it were my code, I might even define constants for red, green, and blue you use with the `Vec3b` type:

```
const int RED_CHAN = 0;
const int GREEN_CHAN = 1;
const int BLUE_CHAN = 2;
```

and then:

```
        int Red = intensity.val[RED_CHAN];
        int Green = intensity.val[GREEN_CHAN];
        int Blue = intensity.val[BLUE_CHAN];
```

It just clarifies what you're pulling out of the array.

Or, since this is C++, you could subclass `Vec3b` to add a `red()`, `green()` and `blue()` method and then just write:

```
int Red = intensity.red();
```

And I'd also make a constant to use instead of the `500` you have for the width of the histogram images.

I'd break this up into 3 functions - `calculateHistogram()`, `drawHistogram()`, and `showImage()`. `calculateHistogram()` would have the double loop where you add up values in the different bins. `drawHistogram()` would generate the `HistPlot*` images, and `showImage()` would create the windows and show the images.

Lastly, I'd add some white space! A blank line here or there to group together related lines helps me mentally organize what's going on.